# Xamarin C# funny code title

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am adjusting myself to code with c# (coming from a java background), learning about new interesting concepts like structs, namespaces, events, partial and delegates.

However I cannot figure out what the following code represents. When starting a new Android solution in Xamarin, the following is displayed below the namespace:

```
[Activity (Label = "CTSPAndroid", MainLauncher = true)]
```

What does this do? What is this called?

Comment: They are attributes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Google: .net attribute programming

Answer (score 7):

As others have answered, this C# feature is called an `Attribute`

These particular `Attribute`s are used by Xamarin to allow it's tools to create entries in the Android Manifest xml file during the application build.

There's a great article on this in http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml

The tools analyze the compiled code in order to turn activities like:

```
[Activity (Label="Awesome Demo App", MainLauncher=true)] 
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
}
```

into xml nodes like:

```
<activity android:name="demo.MyActivity" android:label="Awesome Demo App">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

That's called an [`Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx).

It's similar to java "annotations", I think.